# MariaDB FULLTEXT search with apostrophe, and mandatory words

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select, full-text-search

An apostrophe / single quote (') should be part of a word in a FULLTEXT index.

Admittedly I can't find this on the MariaDB website, but I'm assuming it should still behave like MySQL ([version 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)).

But when using "IN BOOLEAN MODE", and prefixing the word with a "+" (so it's [mandatory in all rows returned](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/full-text-index-overview/)), the record is not returned.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    FULLTEXT (name)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('O''Brien');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('O Brien');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('X''Brien');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('Extra Amy');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('Extra Brian');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('Extra Cat');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('Extra Debbie');
```

I get these results:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("O'Brien" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
  "O'Brien"
  "O Brien"
  "X'Brien"
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)

SELECT * FROM customer WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+O'Brien" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
Empty set (0.000 sec)

SELECT * FROM customer WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+Brien" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
  "O'Brien"
  "O Brien"
  "X'Brien"
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)

SELECT * FROM customer WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (+"O'Brien" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
  "O'Brien"
  "O Brien"
  "X'Brien"
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Am I missing something, like needing to quote the apostrophe?

Or is this an intentional difference between InnoDB and MyISAM?

---

Thanks to @rick-james, I've updated this question to include 3 "extra" records to avoid the 50% threshold limit, and I've included an example where the `+` is before the quoted word.

Comment: How many rows do you have?  Remember the 50% rule.

Comment: Good point, but in the original case I have a table with 48,736 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we create the table with the Aria or MyISAM storage engine, then the query succeeds:

```
CREATE TABLE customer2 (
    name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    FULLTEXT (name)
) ENGINE = Aria;

INSERT INTO customer2 VALUES ('O''Brien');

SELECT * FROM customer2 WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+O'Brien" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

CREATE TABLE customer3 (
    name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    FULLTEXT (name)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO customer3 VALUES ('O''Brien');

SELECT * FROM customer3 WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+O'Brien" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

However, InnoDB doesn't seem to work for me either (MariaDB 10.4.8.)

So that leads me to think this is a bug. I reported the issue here:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20797

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's a bug, and raising it @dbdemon

Comment: For this test, be sure to have more rows _without_ O'Brien than with.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me in both MyISAM and InnoDB.

But note:  out of 185,082 rows, 17 have "O'Brien".  That's less than 50%, so the search term is not ignored.  I verified the count with `LIKE "%O'Brien%"`.

But, when adding the `+`, it needs to be *outside* the quotes for InnoDB.  (Yet another difference between the implementations.)

(I have updated my [*blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#fulltext) to add this diff.)

Comment: In my case (original question), I'm working with 48,736 records, and only 24 records with "O'Brien" (so less than 50%)... and moving the `+` outside of the quote marks seem to change the query so that the "O'" is ignored, and it returns any records that contain the name "Brien".