# MariaDB FULLTEXT search with short / mandatory words

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select, full-text-search

Just checking I'm understanding this correctly:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FULLTEXT (name)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, "ABC.DEF");
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, "ABC_DEF");
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (3, "ABC'DEF");
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (4, "ABC.DE");
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (5, "ABC.DFF");
```

Where I've got `innodb_ft_min_token_size` set to 3 (default is 4).

---

When running:

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    MATCH (name) AGAINST ("+ABC +DEF" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS m
FROM
    customer AS c
```

Customers 1 and 3 match, because the `.` and `'` are seen as word separators ([annoying for O'Brien](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/250524)).

For customer 2, because the underscore gets the whole name treated as a single word, the "DEF" word cannot be found.

---

If I change the MATCH to `"+ABC +DE"`.

1, 2, or 3 do not match because this is using a full word match (`"+DE"` does not match `"DEF"`).

4 does not match because... `innodb_ft_min_token_size` is set to 3?

As in, the 2 letter "DE" word is not in the FULLTEXT INDEX?

---

If I change the MATCH to use asterisks (e.g. `"+ABC* +DE*"`), that will use *prefix* matching.

But will only add customers 1 and 3 to the selection.

Because the 2 letter "DE" word for customer 4 is not in the FULLTEXT INDEX?

---

If I change the MATCH to use `"+ABC.DE*"`, it matches all of them.

Note how they all get the same rank (even customer 5), and this is no different to `"+ABC*"`, where MATCH seems to be seeing the "DE*" as a separate word, and not matching it against anything.

Whereas `"+ABC DE*"` is explicitly keeping it as a separate word, and the scores are handled appropriately.

---

While the individual points make sense, I'm not sure this creates a good system.

For a bit more consistency, I'm wondering if the database should ignore short words (tokens) in the MATCH query, in the same way it does when building the FULLTEXT INDEX.

Only because I don't think `"+DE"` will ever do anything useful when the min token size is 3; and it's not exactly easy for the developer to identify what the individual words in the FULLTEXT INDEX will be (i.e. to remove them).

Answer (score 0):

`FULLTEXT` is imperfect.  You are doing the 'right thing' to analyze the data it this way.  Now switch from "abc" and "def" to strings that are realistic in *your* dataset.

Here are a couple of tricks that I have used reasonably successfully.

- Put a `+` in front of long words, don't put a `+` in front of short words.
- Use this combo to check for things that need `LIKE` (or `RLIKE`) but desire the speed of `FULLTEXT`:

  ```
    WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST ('abc def IN BOOLEAN MODE')
      AND text LIKE '%abc+def%'
  ```

That is, use FT to find rows with the "words", then use `LIKE` to make sure they are adjacent and/or contain certain punctuation.

Comment: That’s an interesting approach. Out of interest, is there a way to split a user supplied string into the individual words that the database sees (“O’Brien” and “first.last” being 2 words, whereas “first_last” is 1 word)... while I’m using PHP in this project, I don’t think that’s necessarily important.

Comment: @CraigFrancis - "O" may give you trouble since it is only one letter.  Especially if you put a "+" in front of it.  Since there are many variations of "+" (or not), "in boolean mode" (or not), word length, stop words, using double-quotes around phrases, etc, you should carefully test.  Note also that a word that show up in "most" rows will be ignored.